# Is it possible to create a desktop widget with react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Does react-native allow the programmer to create a homescreen widget?

When I say widget, I'm saying something for example, the gmail widget which allows you to check your latest emails, something like the image below.

[image: Check]